# Routing with wildcard an pagination in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, routes

In my Cake app, I have the following route:

```
Router::connect('/joints/*', array('controller'=>'joints', 'action'=>'view'));
```

Seems simple enough. I'm using this because I'm using slugs and named parameters, and want clean SEO friendly urls.

The problem is this completely breaks pagination functions.

How can I use a wildcard, but still allow all pagination on the index view to function as expected?

Edit:

The following seems to work, but I wonder if there's a simpler, more elegant way:

```
Router::connect('/joints', array('controller' => 'joints', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/joints/index/*', array('controller' => 'joints', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/burgers/*', array('controller'=>'burgers', 'action'=>'view'));
```

Comment: Please describe your problem with a bit more detail. "It completely breaks" doesn't really tell us very much. What links does it create, what links do you expect? Provide some examples, please.

Comment: Oh sorry. The pagination stops working and Cake throws an error, and the index wont show. When I add a separate route to send "joints" to index, the index now works, but pagination throws the same error: invalid joint, index/sort not found on this server. The wild card is being too greedy. I need a way to let the pagination params pass.